# Callback function parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been following a Node.js tutorial. I always had a doubt in my mind how data are passed to callback function parameters. As an example

```
User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) =>{
    if(err){
        res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register new user'});
    } else {
        res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }
});
```

and addUser function is defined as,

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt)=>{
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

I don't understand how err and user are passed. Can someone explain this?

Comment: They're not passed from here. They're passed from within `newUser.save`. You're just passing the `callback` through to that function, which presumably will eventually call it.

Comment: take a quick look here [return a value from closure to main method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42766223/2359679) , it's for php but i think that it is the same logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `newUser.save` also takes a `callback` parameter and passes it the same kind of parameters. So you can just pass the callback straight into save. I imagine `user.save` would look something like the following:

```
User.prototype.save = function(callback) {
   //do stuff to save the user
   //maybe get an error in the process, or a user record, pass them to the callback
   callback(saveError, userRecord)
}
```

Because the expected args for `save` and `addUser` are the same, the callback can be passed straight into `save`.

Edit: 
I would however suggest to invoke your callback with the error if one is returned from the bcrypt call. Since you already have a callback to give the error to, it doesn't make much sense to throw. Callers will expect errors to come in the callback, so I suggest this instead:

```
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if(err) {
          callback(err, null)
          return
        }
        ...
```

Comment: didn't get this part. "Because the expected args for save and addUser are the same, the callback can be passed straight into save."

Comment: Both the user.save method and your addUser expect a callback where `err` is the first argument and `user` is the second argument. Because of this, a callback passed to addUser could be passed straight to user.save, as the both expect the same callback arguments.